# Repo binary update for CM

Tags: ubuntu, cyanogenmod, repo

I was repo syncing CyanogenMod today and got something like this :

```
hello@hawk:~/CM13$ repo sync

... A new repo command ( 1.22) is available.
... You should upgrade soon:

    cp /home/hello/CM13/.repo/repo/repo /usr/bin/repo
```

Should I do what is given? Or is there a better way to upgrade the binary? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the repo binary in phablet-tools repository of Ubuntu was out-dated, I used the following from this guide http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2639611 on XDA and this solved the issue.

Refer steps 6,7,8 for the solution